# Can we send files using Hangouts Chat API?

Tags: json, api, google-hangouts

Does Hangout Chat allow to send files into a specific chat room.
Instead of uploading the relevant file URL link, can we upload the file directly to a specific chat room?

Answer (score 0):

No we cant!
Right now i think its not possible. I couldnt find similar too